# Group of Tasks condition inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I´m having difficult to combine conditions in Tasks with GroupDescription. If I don´t to use GroupDescription, it works. I need auto select tasks[0] if tasks[2] is selected. I tried:

```
[Tasks]
Name: InstallDS; Description: Install DServer?; GroupDescription: InsDS
Name: InstallTG; Description: Install TServer?; GroupDescription: InsDS
Name: InstallOP; Description: Install Optionals?; GroupDescription: InsDS

[Code]
procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[0] := WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[2];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
    begin
        TasksListClickCheck(WizardForm.TasksList);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you add GroupDescription, the Consecutive Tasks below the group will be arranged as elements 1,2,3. [Inno Tasks section description](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection)

```
procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[3] = True) then
    begin
      WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[1] := True;
    end;  
end;
```

Comment: When you use 2 groups, as explained above, Group 2 elements will be (5,6,7). Element (4) for group description. That's how it behaves.

Comment: [Tasks]
Name: InstallDS01; Description: Install DS01?; GroupDescription: InsDS01. 
 Name: InstallDS02; Description: Install DS02?; GroupDescription: InsDS02.
[Code]
procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[2] = True) then
    begin
      WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[1] := True;
    end;  
end;
But didn´t work